# If I have to fetch complete table all the time, what will be effect of indexing?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm creating a registration app, where I make users to register themselves. 
Now admin has option to fetch export all registered users to CSV/Excel file. Records could be thousands. I can't fetch them all in once in one row, how to make it fast ? Will indexing help ?

Answer (score 0):

When exporting the entire table, *all* data must be read.
Adding an index cannot reduce the amount of data.

An index would help only if you sort the output by some column(s).

Comment: Which of these five words do you not understand?

Comment: **READ**
what you mean by read, while fetching we are reading technically. What are you pointing too ?

Comment: sorry your answer isn't helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Indexing will generally help when reading or updating a subset of data in the table, such as a single row or group or rows.

For example, if you wanted to allow all the data to be exported, or even viewed, one page at a time, a primary key field with an index can be used to retrieve a subset, such as 20, rows at a time, resulting in a better "perceived" performance, rather than waiting for the entire table to be exported before viewing any of the data.

Comment: that's cool, you described well what indexing is and what it does.
What is solution to my problem ? how to handle it ?

Comment: If you wanted to make subsequent exports faster, you can add a column as a flag to determine if the record has already been exported, and only export records where the "exported" column is false.  Then add an index to this column.